# elem.text is not a function in JSDOM

Tags: javascript, jsdom

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom'

const virtualConsole = jsdom.createVirtualConsole()

virtualConsole.on('jsdomError', ({stack, detail}) => console.error(stack, detail))

global.document = jsdom.jsdom(`
  <html>
    <body>
      <div id="foo">some text</div>
    </body>
  </html>
`, { virtualConsole })

global.window = document.defaultView
global.navigator = window.navigator

const elem = document.getElementById('foo')
console.log('foo text', elem.text())
```

This gives me the wonderful error `elem.text is not a function`

I'm using JSDOM v9.1.0

What am I missing?

Comment: What function did you expect `.text()` to be? This is the DOM, not jQuery. Try `elem.innerText` or `elem.textContent` instead.

Comment: `.text()` is not a DOM function. It's a jQuery  function.

Comment: @Bergi `innerText` is not supported by JSDOM, so it'll need to be `textContent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text()` is a jQuery method that returns the text content of a given element(s). It isn't actually part of the JavaScript DOM API I'm afraid. Try using the `.textContent` property. ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)).

```
const elem = document.getElementById('foo')
console.log('foo text', elem.textContent)
```

Comment: Haha damn -_-. I had actually used innerText before but used it as a function instead of a property. Thanks for waking me up